# Open source text editor with a "save draft" feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, jwysiwyg

Our current Rails application is using jwysiwyg for our text editor but it is not very feature rich. We want:

- User to be able to save their work and return to it later if necessary. A "Save draft" feature similar to what Wordpress uses would be great.
- Upload images from their hardrive rather than have to copy and paste an image URL.

What options are out there that will provide us with these two features? Is it possible to expand upon the currently existing jwysiwyg? Or would we have to go with an alternative option? We are currently using wysiwyg through Javascript integration but we are open to a Rails Ruby gem alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to drafts is that they are really versions... so a version control system is really what you want.

Nowadays that's usually a distributed one such as git.

I would get into the workflow of using git and have that be your process for drafts.

So use an IDE that supports DVCS, for example Eclipse can include git support.

Comment: I only want to save drafts for the most recent post. I.e, we're only saving one draft at any given time. Would I still need a version control system?

Comment: I'm sure it seems like overkill (and maybe it is) but most of what you need is in a DVCS.  It's ability to do a couple of things well (like this) are what makes it a winner.  If you're involved at all with code down the line, you'll be glad to pick up the 'required' skill.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to the Eclipse editor that you mentioned? I did a quick google search and came across different types.

Comment: Google eclipse IDE and the first link is: http://www.eclipse.org/  also there is http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html which shows you how to issue git commands from Eclipse.